# Multiple comparisons in an if statement using the logical OR operator

Tags: javascript

I want to do he following, but it does not work:

```
if(pathname == '/ik/services/' || '/ik/recruitment/'){
   //run function
}
```

It is completely ignoring my if statement and executes the code for all pages...

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/boolean.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to do something like this:

```
if(pathname == '/ik/services/' || pathname == '/ik/recruitment/'){
   //run function
}
```

Your `|| '/ik/recruitment/'` would always be [truthy](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/), and therfor the code within your if-statement will always run.

Comment: Upvote for being the only answer out of five that actually explains why the OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: @rrikesh Weird, I swear it worked just a minute ago. I'll try to track down another good resource on truthy/falsy and update my answer. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The Google Cache says it was available in March. But I find it strange that is not found right now

Comment: @DavidVanStaden My pleasure! Updated my answer with another read on truthy/falsy values, that hopefully works better.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
if(pathname == '/ik/services/' || pathname == '/ik/recruitment/'){
```

**OR**

jQuery **[`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)**

**Example**

```
var arr = ['/ik/services/','/ik/recruitment/'];

if($.inArray(pathname , arr) !== -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with jQuery, it's just a normal JS "error". You need to compare both strings with the variable:

```
if (pathname == 'foo'  || pathname == 'bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if((pathname == '/ik/services/') || (pathname == '/ik/recruitment/')){
   //run function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
    if(pathname == '/ik/services/' || pathname == '/ik/recruitment/'){
      //run function
    }
```